# How do I configure a PPTP VPN?

Tags: 8.1

I'm using PPTP to connect my laptop and Surface to the corporate network. How do I connect my Nokia Lumia 920 with Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview to the network using PPTP?

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 8.1 does not support PPTP VPN

According to [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn673608.aspx), the only VPN protocols that are supported are:

- IKEv2 - Supported natively
- SSL-VPN - Supported for third-party servers via a plug-in model

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to get a VPN profile onto your phone, either by setting up a Workplace account, or by creating one manually in Settings -> VPN, and tap <kbd>+</kbd> and then fill in your server name or IP address, and username/password.

If your particular VPN is not available in the Type drop down, you can tap the "Download an SSL VPN app from the Store" link below to get the app for your provider (Be it SonicWall, Check Point, etc.)

I don't believe it's possible to share the VPN connection via the Internet Sharing feature - instead that shares the current Internet Connection, which your tablet (PC, etc.) can use, and connect to the VPN separately over that shared connection.

Comment: PPTP doesn't seem to be available in the Store.

Comment: PPTP is not supported natively by Windows Phone (at least for the Dev Preview, who knows if the final release will), nor does it seem to be possible for 3rd party Store apps to support it as Store apps can only provide SSL VPN such as those proprietary ones from vendors like Cisco and Dell (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Seems therea are still no PPTP apps in the store if i'm right?